# Terraform list all running ec2 instances excluding those filtered by tag name

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I'd like to to be able to exclude certain ec2 instances by tag:Name values, but list all the rest.

```
data "aws_instances" "filtered_running_instances" {
  instance_state_names = ["running"]
    filter {
      name = "tag:Name"
      values = ["tagvalue"]
    }
}
```

Will list the desired instances, but is there anyway to invert this? The only other way I can think of is subtracting the above from a full set of running instances, but this seems inelegant!